# Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7: Java 1.8 or later is required

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I just updated to `IntelliJ IDEA 16` which comes with `Java JDK 1.8`. Fyi, I had downloaded Java JDK 1.8 a long time ago.

I tried to run my plugin that I am developing, and I cannot even do that, I get the following error message (slightly condensed)

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" -Xmx512m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -ea "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 144.3143.6\lib\boot.jar" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\Christopher.IdeaIC14\system\plugins-sandbox\config - ... -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\tools.jar; ... ;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 144.3143.6\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.idea.Main
>
> **Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_45-b18: Java 1.8 or later is required.**

**So, I clearly know what the problem is; however, I cannot seem to figure out where the location to fix this is.**

I have tried a lot of things so far; most involve using the **search box** in `Settings` and switching whatever I could to version 1.8. Also, I had updated my `Environment Variable` for Java from 1.6 to 1.8

With all of these changes, nothing is working! So how do I go about fixing this seemingly simple issue?

Comment: Check the Project Structure section under "File" menu. There's also something to change there (sorry, I can't recall exactly at the moment)

Comment: You most likely have set JAVA_HOME

Comment: @Avi I think your idea is correct, I seen references to Java 7 in the Project Structure. EDIT: your idea fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Set `IDEA_JDK` (or `IDEA_JDK_64`) environment variable.
Check [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

Comment: won't matter, IntelliJ 16 can't be run on a Java 7 or older JVM.

Comment: @jwenting - What won't matter??? He needs to set JDK_18 for startup. He asks how to do so.

Comment: Had misread the question as him wanting to run IntelliJ 16 under Java 7, which will never work.

Comment: Finally an actual way to set the JDK for IDEA only without screwing up existing environment variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** --> Set **JAVA_HOME** to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51**

Java 8 is required to run IntelliJ IDEA starting from version 16 on all the supported platforms.

The **actual JDK version** used by the IDE can be verified in **Help | About dialog** (open any project to access the menu).

```
idea64.exe uses this JDK search in the following sequence:

IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable
..\jre64 directory
system Registry
JDK_HOME environment variable
JAVA_HOME environment variable
```

Answer (score 4):

Under Arch Linux you can simply set java 8 as default (you must have it installed):

```
$ sudo archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk
```

Comment: Can't believe this doesn't get more votes. How did I not know about `archlinux-java`... -- Edit, oh the OP is asking for windows, I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone arrives here and hasn't had any luck with the other solutions, try this.  I'm using PhpStorm under OSX, but the steps are probably applicable to JetBrains' other IDEs too:

1. Navigate to your IDE's config folder (see [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to learn how to find this folder's location).
2. Open the **idea.propeties** file.
3. If a `JVMVersion` attribute exists, delete that entire entry. If it doesn't exist, then this probably won't be of much help!
4. Save the file.
5. Launch your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just set JAVA_HOME system variable to your JDK 8:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run in cmd

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
```

don't foget to change to your java path

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Ubuntu 14 (32-bit), I opened the file:

```
/home/<user>/Programs/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

and after

```
if [ "$JDK" = "" ] && [ "$OS_TYPE" = "Linux" ] && ........... fi
```

I added:

```
if [ "$JDK" = "" ]; then
    JDK="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
fi
```

And then it works!

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your **JAVA_HOME** points to the correct 1.8 Installation and make sure that in the **PATH** env there is no reference to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin".
Try to **print your JAVA_HOME/PATH** from the Console and see what the output is. If your changes are not reflected logout and then login again.

Comment: I have already checked that part. I mentioned `Environment Variable` in my question, and those values are correct

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 16 REQUIRES Java 8 to run, it won't run under Java 7. It's compiled to Java 8 classes so it can't ever be run on an older JVM.
This is well and clearly mentioned in the documentation.

So if you have your system JVM be an older one, it will fail to start unless you coerce it into using a non-default JVM. 
Possibly you have some java related executables left over in your Windows/System32 directory, where some older Java installers would drop them. Delete these by hand from the file system and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this page needs one more recommendation, I fixed the problem in my case by going to the IDE's config folder (as @Nate puts it, see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) for how to locate it), and deleting the `idea.jdk` file (which held a reference to a 1.6 VM).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting the correct Java version for the global, per project and per module SDK, for the Java Compiler, and for the language level, you also must set the **Target bytecode version** both for the project ***and*** (if you use maven) for each maven module.

Often the project bytecode version is correct but the module bytecode version is lower, i.e. 1.5.

[image: Intellij Idea: target bytecode version for maven module]

The per-module bytecode version is **not displayed** when opening the *default* preferences via **File** > **Other Settings** > **Default Settings**. You must edit the ***current preferences*** either via a shortcut (i.e. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) or from the main menu as shown below (for mac):

[image: Intellij Idea current preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All paths pointing to java jdk 8, but still throwing the error. I was able to run Android Studio by running the "studio64.exe" instead "studio.exe" in the bin folder