# how do I know if my code base has java 8 methods

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am having some problems where AppEngine is complaining that my code has Java 1.8 methods, whereas AppEngine requires Java 1.7. Here is the error trace. I am not sure how to fix it.

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@6c5c4442{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~myapi-mobile/1.123456789034567}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:203)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:133)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:501)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-9f0a91645afbfd1f(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:820)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-9f0a91645afbfd1f(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:820)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921899/unsupported-java-version-cannot-start-under-java-1-7-java-1-8-or-later-is-requ?s=2|2.5599

Answer (score 2):

The message does **not** tell that you have *Java8 methods*, it tells that your Java files have been **compiled** using *Java8 compiler* whereas the execution environment is an earlier Java version.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75527  QUOTE:: In general, the Java compiler has never enforced API compliance, so as an example you can compile a program with JDK 7, using -source 1.6 and -target 1.6, and *still* reference APIs from JDK 7 that are not available in JDK 6, and everything will compile smoothly (as long as you are referencing the new APIs without using any of the Java 7 language syntax). And obviously it won't run on Java 6 because of the missing API. In short, the compiler doesn't enforce that; it only enforces language compliance, using whatever APIs ...

Comment: this post on google code is about somthing diffferent. Its about the runtime dependency to methods available in libs of Java8. if you want to wvoid that you need to configure your IDE to compile against the JRE of your target Java version.

Comment: Indeed. If you were trying to use a method that wasn't available, you'd get a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question, you can attempt to compile your code using a Java 7 (or lower) compiler, and see what happens.

If the code compiles without issue, it's likely not using Java 8 methods (although that isn't necessary true, there could be Java 8 methods called using reflection).

If there are exceptions, you would have to inspect the exceptions to see their root cause.

If the errors report methods that don't obviously exist (e.g. the new collections/ streams API), or they report unrecognised syntax (e.g. using lambdas, `() -> {}`), then you are likely using Java 8.